# "join" vs "join in"

Tags: verb-usage

I've heard that you have to say "join someone" and "join in something". I am going to make up a few pairs of sentences below.

> (1a) I will **join** you for John's birthday lunch tomorrow.
>
> (1b) I will **join in** for John's birthday lunch tomorrow.
>
> (2a) I will **join** you for his retirement party next week.
>
> (2b) I will **join in** his retirement party next week.
>
> (3a) I will **join** the international comic event next month.
>
> (3b) I will **join in** the international comic event next month.

I think both (1) and (2) follow the correct usage. I believe that you can say "join an event" without adding a pronoun after "join" because you will participate in it. "join in an event" is the correct usage.

Am I using "join" and "join in" correctly in all my sentences?

Comment: Why did anyone downvote this? It's an earnest question

Answer (score 4):

1a and 2a are the only ones that sound correct to me.

to join-in means to take part in or to become involved in. It's something that's already happening when the subject joins in.

> He joined in dancing

The dancing was already ongoing when "he" started.

> Don't you want to join in the fun?

The "fun" (party, festival, whatever) is already taking place.

I wouldn't use join in for a broad event. "She joined in the convention" would sound odd to me, because a convention isn't any one specific activity.

When talking about events and just using join, we wouldn't generally say join with the event itself. We join someone **for** the event.

> He joined us for the work party.

Answer (score 2):

"Join in" doesn't really fit in any of your examples. In fact, I'm not sure "join" alone works for example 3 either.

"Join in" idiomatically means to "get involved" with something, for example:

> I joined in with the laughter.

"Join" alone means to *unite* or *connect* with someone or something.

I would use "join" for your first two examples:

> I will join you for John's birthday lunch tomorrow.
>   I will join you for his retirement party next week.

But for your third example, the "event" is something you are *attending*, rather than getting *involved* or *connecting* with.

> I will attend the international comic event next month.